# Erro ao tentar gravar comboBox e MaskTextBox

Tags: c#, postgresql, visual-studio

Tenho um formulário com dois campos:

- 1 ComboBox que coloquei o tipo da pessoas (Fisica ou Juridica);
- 1 MaskTextBox com o CPF;

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A principio não sei o que é melhor se é guardar o valor do `Index` da combobox ou o texto dela. Porque depois quando for fazer uma busca irei precisar carregar esse combobox novamente.

Meu banco está assim:

```
CREATE TABLE CLIENTES(
    id_cliente SERIAL PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    tipo INT,
    tipos VARCHAR(10),
    CPF INT
);
```

Fiz bem simples para aprender e deixei os `tipos/tipo` para testar as duas formas.

Minha classe de conexão e o método para Inserir:

```
class DAL
    {
        static string serverName = "localhost";
        static string port = "5432";
        static string userName = "postgres";
        static string password = "adm";
        static string databaseName = "dbestoque";
        NpgsqlConnection conn = null;
        string ConnString = null;

        public DAL()
        {
            ConnString = String.Format("Server={0};Port={1};User Id={2};Password={3};Database={4};",
                                       serverName, port, userName, password, databaseName);

        }
 public void InserirClientes(int cb, int cpf)
        {
            using (conn = new NpgsqlConnection(ConnString))
            {
                conn.Open();
                string cmdInserir = String.Format("INSERT INTO CLIENTES(tipo, cpf) VALUES ('{0}', '{1}')", cb, cpf);

                using (NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(cmdInserir, conn))
                {
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
        }
```

Botão para gravar:

```
private void btnGravar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DAL n = new DAL();
        try
        {
            n.InserirClientes(cbTipo.SelectedIndex, Convert.ToInt16(mskCPF.Text));
        }catch(Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Efetuado");
        }

    }
```

Erro:

```
System.FormatException ocorrido
  HResult=0x80131537
  Message=A cadeia de caracteres de entrada não estava em um formato correto.
  Source=ProjetoAlpha
  StackTrace:
   em ProjetoAlpha.frmCadastros.btnGravar_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) em C:\Users\willian\source\repos\ProjetoAlpha\ProjetoAlpha\frmCadastros.cs:linha 28
   em System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   em System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   em System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
   em System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   em System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   em System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
   em System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
   em System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   em System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   em System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
   em System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
   em System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
   em System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   em System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   em System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
   em ProjetoAlpha.Program.Main() em C:\Users\willian\source\repos\ProjetoAlpha\ProjetoAlpha\Program.cs:linha 19
```

Answer (score 0):

Existe uma maneira diferente que você pode salvar o tipo de cliente:

- Altere o campo "tipo" do banco de dados, de `INT` para `VARCHAR`
- Atribua o text da ComboBox a uma String, e ai sim grave ela no banco de dados.

Também tive essa duvida em uma aplicação que desenvolvi em VB, e resolvi desse jeito.

Abaixo, um exemplo da aplicação (feita em VB) :

```
    Dim sexo As String
    sexo = cbosexocli.Text.ToUpper.First

    comando.CommandText = ("insert into clientes(codcli, nomecli, salariocli, sexocli, nascimento) values(" & txtcodcli.Text & ",'" & txtnomecli.Text & "'," & txtsalariocli.Text & ",'" & sexo & "',CONVERT(datetime,'" & msknascimentocli.Text & "',103))")
```

Comment: só use TEXT para campos muito grandes, e que não precisem de busca, o normal é o VARCHAR mesmo

Comment: Obrigado pela dica Rovann ! Já alterei isso no meu comentário.

Answer (score 0):

Alguns pontos para alterar:

**1-** 
Alteraria o controle, ao invés de um comboBox, utilizaria um radioBox, fica mais simples e você passa a armazenar apenas um boolean:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**2-** Altere o tipo de dado do CPF, que também pode ser CNPJ. Uma variável `integer` só vai até +2147483647, com isso, sempre dará erro pelo tamanho do cpf/cnpj. Eu utilizaria VarChar(18) e já gravaria com a máscara.

**3-** Utilize `NpgsqlParameter` para passar os parâmetros para o command, é o correto até por questões de segurança.

Não tenho exemplo do Npgsql aqui, mas assim que puder altero a resposta.

> Obs: o Erro atual, acontece no seguinte ponto: `Convert.ToInt16(mskCPF.Text)`.
>    Se tentasse colocar Int64 ainda passaria, mas daria erro no postgres. Int32 já não cabe um CPF, Int16 então...

Espero que ajude.